# how can we restrict after login go back to login page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have  two controllers

1.**Login**

2.**Dashboard**

In Login controller I have two methods

1.*logged_in*()

2.*logged_out*()

This is my Login Controller

```
public function logged_in()
{
    $user_email =$this->input->post('user_email');
    $user_password =$this->input->post('user_password');
    $result=$this->Login_model->login_data($user_email,$user_password);
    if(!$result)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('failure', 'Login failed');
        redirect(BASE_URL.'admin/Login');
    }
    else
    {
        $data=array(
            'user_email'=>$result[0]['user_email'],
            'user_password'=>$result[0]['user_password'],
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('session_data',$data); 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Login sucessfully');
        redirect(BASE_URL.'admin/Dashboard');
    }
}

public function logged_out()
{
   $this->session->unset_userdata('session_data');
   $this->session->sess_destroy();
   $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Logout sucessfully');
   redirect(BASE_URL.'admin/Login');
}
```

And this is Dashboard controller :

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('session_data')!='')
        {
            $this->load->view('admin/dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('admin_flash', 'Try again');
            redirect(BASE_URL."admin/Login");
        }
    }
}
```

I have a problem while after login it enters in my view which I have to load but the problem is that if I go back it goes to login page which i don't want.
so suggest me solution?

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to make something like a boolean called `logged` by default false and set it true when the user log into the page and false if you log out. Then check if the user is login in the login page and if he's login redirect the user to the homepage

Answer (score 0):

simply check whether user logged in or not in your login page. If user is already logged in, redirect him/her to dashboard.

In your code:

```
public function logged_in()
{
    // check whether user is logged in or not, 
    // if yes redirect them to dashboard
    if($this->session->userdata('session_data')!='')
    {
        redirect(BASE_URL."admin/dashboard");
    }

    $user_email =$this->input->post('user_email');
    $user_password =$this->input->post('user_password');
    $result=$this->Login_model->login_data($user_email,$user_password);
    if(!$result)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('failure', 'Login failed');
        redirect(BASE_URL.'admin/Login');
    }
    else
    {
        $data=array(
            'user_email'=>$result[0]['user_email'],
            'user_password'=>$result[0]['user_password'],
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('session_data',$data); 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Login sucessfully');
        redirect(BASE_URL.'admin/Dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: But it still goes back to login page even after login